# Can the wrapper functions be refactored

Tags: c++

I have a collection of C++ functions that all accept a type from the same set of types (`TypeA`, `TypeB` and `TypeC` in the example below) as template parameter. To ease the exposition of these functions to python, I would like to define, for each of them, a function that takes the type not as template parameter, but as a string argument, as shown below:

```
template<typename dataType>
int function(int arg)
{
    ...
}

int function(int arg, string type)
{
    if (type == "type_A")
    {
        return function<TypeA>(arg);
    }
    else if (type == "type_B")
    {
        return function<TypeB>(arg);
    }
    else if (type == "type_C")
    {
        return function<TypeC>(arg);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid type!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

At the moment, I wrap all the functions in this way, but this leads to a lot of code repetition, so I was wondering whether there was a better way to do this, perhaps using preprocessor directives?

Comment: If that function takes an `int` and returns an `int`, what does it use the template parameter for?

Comment: @Beta That could be anything. For example it could be a functor type describing what to do to the argument. It might also be a tag type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: A functor type describing what to do to the argument? I understand using a *functor* or a *function pointer* for that purpose, but a *functor type?* And I'm new to tags, but I don't (yet) see the point of that either.

Comment: @Beta Tag types are types that don't do anything useful at runtime but are used to identify categories or characteristics, usually used to identify one of multiple specializations for use. For example `function` might be specialized for `t_tag_square` such that it squares the input.  Although it may not the first solution to come to mind, passing functors as types to templates can work just as well as passing instances of functors. Provided those functions have compatible constructors. In this case, standard functor types that could work include `std::negate` and `std::bit_not`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Yes, I understand that it *can* be done; I'm studying the question of *why it ought to* be done, what circumstances would lead it to it being not just a workable solution, but the best solution. I think it will take me some time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to reduce the `if/else` logic is to store a map of `std::function` objects and use the map to make the right call.

```
int function(int arg, std::string type)
{
   using FMap = std::map<std::string, std::function<int(int)>>;
   static const FMap fmap{{"type_A", [](int arg) { return function<TypeA>(arg); }},
                          {"type_B", [](int arg) { return function<TypeB>(arg); }},
                          {"type_C", [](int arg) { return function<TypeC>(arg); }}};

   auto iter = fmap.find(type);
   if ( iter != fmap.end() )
   {
      return iter->second(arg);
   }

   std::cerr << "Invalid type!" << std::endl;
   exit(1);
   return 0;
}
```

If you are willing to rename the function template, you can simplify the code for constructing the function map.

```
template <typename T>
int fun_2(int arg) { ... }

int function(int arg, std::string type)
{
   using FMap = std::map<std::string, std::function<int(int)>>;
   static const FMap fmap{{"type_A", fun_2<TypeA>},
                          {"type_B", fun_2<TypeB>},
                          {"type_C", fun_2<TypeC>}};

   auto iter = fmap.find(type);
   if ( iter != fmap.end() )
   {
      return iter->second(arg);
   }

   std::cerr << "Invalid type!" << std::endl;
   exit(1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: However, a small confusion in lambda. Shouldn't be the same lambda for all, since it always takes an `int` and same return also its a templated one.

Comment: @JeJo, that won't work. Each lambda is slightly different.

Comment: @RSahu Hmm Okay. I have also noticed that OP has the same, in his example code.

Comment: Could array of pairs<string/string_view/char*, fn_ptr> be enough ? It seems overdone to me, even for 1000 overloads the code would still run fine I beleive

Comment: @Riptide, using `std::vector<std::pair<...>>` will work but the code is a bit simpler with `std::map`. For such small data sizes, it's better to use simpler code.